# Confused in implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I quoted an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Person
{
    public Person(string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

public class People : IEnumerable
{
    private Person[] _people;
    public People(Person[] pArray)
    {
        _people = new Person[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _people[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
    }

    public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PeopleEnum(_people);
    }
}

public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public Person[] _people;

    // Enumerators are positioned before the first element 
    // until the first MoveNext() call. 
    int position = -1;

    public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
    {
        _people = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _people.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public Person Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _people[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person[] peopleArray = new Person[3]
        {
            new Person("John", "Smith"),
            new Person("Jim", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Sue", "Rabon"),
        };

        People peopleList = new People(peopleArray);
        foreach (Person p in peopleList)
            Console.WriteLine(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);

    }
}

/* This code produces output similar to the following:
 *
 * John Smith
 * Jim Johnson
 * Sue Rabon
 *
 */
```

### Questions

1. What is making a copy of `Person[]` in `People` ctor for?
2. Why does `People` implement `GetEnumerator` by returning `PeopleEnum` via a new overloading method `public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()`? Is the new method `public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()` necessarily needed?
3. With the same pattern, why does `PeopleEnum` implement `Current` by returning `Person` via a new property `public Person Current`? Is the new property `public Person Current` necessarily needed?

### My Code (for comparison)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ExtensionMethod
{

    sealed class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    sealed class PeopleEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        Person[] people;
        int position = -1;

        public PeopleEnumerator(Person[] people)
        {
            this.people = people;
        }

        bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return position < people.Length;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return people[position];
            }
        }

        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            position = -1;
        }
    }

    sealed class People : IEnumerable
    {
        private Person[] people;

        public People(Person[] people)
        {
            this.people = people;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new PeopleEnumerator(people);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            People people = new People(
                new[]{
                    new Person {Name="Andy",Age=23},
                    new Person {Name="Bobby",Age=22}
           });

            foreach (Person p in people)
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since c# 2.0, the most common way of writing custom iterators has been via iterator blocks. It is very uncommon to do this manually.

Comment: Why not use `yield` keyword and just implement `IEnumerable<Person>`.

Comment: @ja72: I don't know why the author of MSDN did not use `yield`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is making a copy of `Person[]` in `People` constructor for?

Because if you stored a reference then any changes to the source array would be reflected in the collection.  By copying the items you decouple the collection from the source.

> Why does `People` implement `GetEnumerator` by returning `PeopleEnum` via a new overloading method `public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()`? Is the new method `public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()` necessarily needed?

The overload provides a *strongly-typed* enumerator rather than the basic `IEnumerator` interface. That allows `foreach` to return the actual types in the collection without casting to object (or boxing if the underlying type was a value type)

> With the same pattern, why does `PeopleEnum` implement `Current` by returning `Person` via a new property `public Person Current`? Is the new property `public Person Current` necessarily needed?

For the same reason - so `foreach` can return the actual types without casting (or boxing)

In essence, `foreach` will use "duck typing" and use the strongly-typed `GetEnumerator`, `Next`, and `Current` instead of the `IEnumerator` interface methods.

You can read [Eric Lippert's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) on `foreach` to better understand the value of duck-typing and strongly-typed enumerators.

Comment: Does casting from `object` really happen? Or it is done implicitly? Because I did not see it.

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood sorry, that should read "to `object`". I have fixed that. And yes, it's implicit in `IEnumerator.Current`.